# Saying hagomel on behalf of small kids

Tags: halacha, blessing, minor-katan-child, hagomel

In the case when a small kid was in danger and saved, is it possible for a parent to recite hagomel on behalf of him?

The question is twofold:

1. If the child is too young to recite the blessing, can the father say it instead of him?
2. Even when he is old enough to recite the blessing physically but is too immature to understand that he was in danger, would it be possible for a parent to thank Hashem on his behalf?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20022&st=&pgnum=59

Comment: Seem that there are 2 aspects to this question - 1) Birkat Hagomel seems to be a Rabbinical mitzvah. Children are generally not obligated in mitzvoth, so, perhaps they don't have this obligation. If that's the case, it seems dad cannot do it for him. 2) It may not be limited to children. Let's say an adult was saved from danger. But, he suffers trauma and physically cannot say the bracha. Can another adult do it for him? In light of my 2nd question, I don't know if you want to edit yours to make it more "broad".

Answer (score 3):

Piskei Teshuvos OC 219:9 says:

> שם: עוד כתבו דקטן אינו מחויב להודות, ואפילו מצד מצוות חינוך. כי35 אין יכול לומר הגומל 'לחייבים' שהרי עדיין אינו בר חיובא, ואם הכוונה על אביו, אין זה מן הכבוד שבן יאמר כן, וגם האב36 לא יברך הגומל על בנו, וכן נתפשט37 המנהג בכל תפוצות ישראל, אם כי קיימים כמה משיטות הפוסקים38 הסוברים שקטן שהגיע לחינוך יברך הגומל, ויש39 הכותבים שהנכון שיברך בלשון בריך רחמנא מלכא דעלמא הגומל לחייבים וכו'.

In short, according to Magen Avraham here and Avnei Nezer OC:39 among many others, a child under Bar Mitzvah is not required to ever make a blessing of Hagomel, as he cannot say the phrase "Lechayavim". Shaarei Teshuvah here (in the name of Shaarei Efraim and Machazik Beracha here) says that a father should not make this blessing on behalf of his son, and Piskei Teshuvos based on various Poskim, says that it is the universal Minhag for both Ashkenazim and Sefardim that parents do not make this blessing on behalf of their children.

Edit:

However, Rav Yehuda Herzl Henkin in [Shu"t Benei Banim 2:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20022&st=&pgnum=63) (h/t to DoubleAA) works his way thoroughly through the Poskim to prove that it is permissible for a father to make Birchas Hagomel, and says that he himself made Hagomel (albeit with slightly different wording), and published this Pesak.  Here is his conclusion:

> והנה על בתי הקטנה ברכתי הגומל לחייבים טובות שגמל לבתי כל טוב והתכוונתי על עצמי שכיון שהיא קטנה היא כחלק מגופי

From the rest of the Poskim, however, it seems that this is a minority opinion.  Tzitz Eliezer (not quoted by Piskei Teshuvos) 14:20 quotes various Poskim (that say that this is Assur, and he concludes that it is **obvious** that a father may not make this Beracha on his son.  (At one point, he even says ולענין אבי הקטן מעלה גם הברכ"י בעצמו בספרו מחזיק ברכה אות ו' כדעת ספר אהל יוסף דלא יברך אלא בלא הזכרת שם ומלכות, **ובלי חולק** ע"ש ). (He also notes that this is the prevalent Minhag.)

Here is his conclusion about a father making the Beracha:

> ועוד יעוין בס' נמוקי או"ח להגאון ממונקאטש ז"ל שהעלה ג"כ דאין להורות לקטן לברך ולעשות כנגד דברי המג"א, **ושפשיטא שגם אביו אינו מברך בעדו**. וכן בספר שו"ת נחלת בנימין חאו"ח סי' נ"ח נו"נ =נושא ונותן= באריכות בדברי המהר"ם מינץ והמהר"י באסאן ועוד. וסיים להלכה בזה"ל: והנה כמה גאוני חכמי ספרד כתבו שיש לקטן לברך ברכת הגומל, ואפ"ה במדינתנו אין נוהגין כך **ואין מברך לא האב** ולא בנו הקטן פחות מי"ג שנים וסומכין על תשו' מהר"מ מינץ והמג"א וא"ר הביאו ולא חלקו, א"כ אע"ג שהקטן לפי שכלו בתורה הי' ראוי לברך **מ"מ אין לחדש דבר ופוק חזי מאי עמא דבר עכ"ל.**

Comment: "it is the universal Minhag" The link in my comment above is one counterexample to this. Not that _Piskei Teshuvos_ is well known for citing the full gamut of opinions...

Comment: @DoubleAA, fair point. Tbh, the Benei Banim is the exception here, rather than the rule. In the beginning portion of the teshuva, he himself quotes the Taz, Biur Halacha, Elya Rabbah, Birkei Yosef etc. that it is Assur to make it.  He quotes a list of other Acharonim (Bach, Shyarei KH"G, Aruch Hashulchan etc.) who say it is Muttar to make it.  However, even according to those Poskim who allow others to bless on behalf of those close to them, the Minhag seems to be that it was not made.  cont->

Comment: @DoubleAA As evidenced by Aruha"sh Seif 9, where he says that a wife would be a classic example of this, yet the minhag is that the husband does not make Hagomel on her behalf.  "ומזה למדו דאשה שנתחייבה בברכת הגומל יכול הבעל לברך בעדה ולכן כשילדה ונצולה מן הסכנה יכול הבעל לברך שגמלך כל טוב והיא תענה אמן דאין לך אהבה ונוגע בטובתה יותר ממנו דאשתו כגופו [ב"ח ומג"א סק"ד] דלא כיש מי שמפקפק בזה [עב"י וט"ז סק"ג] ומ"מ אין המנהג כן"

Comment: @DoubleAA However, I will add in a line about this, thanks for providing a good source.